# Using CRectTracker in CWinAppEx causes assertion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I added the MFC CRectTracker to a CWinAppEx based application but the constructor of CRectTracker fails with an assert. By looking and debugging into the MFC source I can see that it is because CRectTracker is trying to use AfxGetResourceHandle() that fails because AfxGetModuleState()->m_hCurrentResourceHandle is NULL.

The strange thing is that, if I for the sake of the test, convert CWinAppEx to CWinApp it Works. There's a Tracker sample in the MFC samples that works - but it uses CWinApp. IF I change CWinApp to CWinAppEx, it fails too.

I use VS2010. Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: AfxGetResourceHandle Returns always a valid handle and never Returns NULL. At least it Returns the handle to the current EXE. Something is wrong in your code. Tell me the exact location for the ASSERT

Comment: HINSTANCE AFXAPI AfxFindResourceHandle(LPCTSTR lpszName, LPCTSTR lpszType)
{
   ...
 AFX_MODULE_STATE* pModuleState = AfxGetModuleState();
 if (!pModuleState->m_bSystem)
 {
  hInst = AfxGetResourceHandle();  // <<<<
  if (::FindResource(hInst, lpszName, lpszType) != NULL)
  {
   return hInst;
  }
 }
   ...
}

From afxwin1.inl:
_AFXWIN_INLINE HINSTANCE AFXAPI AfxGetResourceHandle()
 { ASSERT(afxCurrentResourceHandle != NULL); // <<<<
  return afxCurrentResourceHandle; }

From afxwin.h:
#define afxCurrentResourceHandle    AfxGetModuleState()->m_hCurrentResourceHandle

Comment: I have created a test project with the VS project wizard. If I use CRectTracker it crashes in the same way. 
I can send it but I'm not sure whether it is possible to upload files here?